# getElementsByTagName not working in IE when returning XML file?

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to select certain elements from an XML file via JavaScript, I've got it working in Firefox, Chrome and IE9+ but IE8 is proving to be a real stumbling block, I'm using the code below to return the XML file:

```
        function httpGet(theUrl) {
            var xmlHttp = null;

            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.open('GET', theUrl, false);
            xmlHttp.send();

            if(window.DOMParser) {
                var parser = new DOMParser();
                var doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlHttp.responseText, 'text/xml');
                return doc;
            }
            else {
                var xmlDocument = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
                xmlDocument.async = false;
                xmlDocument.loadXML(xmlHttp.responseText);
                return xmlDocument;
            }
        }
```

I'm then using the below selectors to make a list of certain items in the XML file:

```
    var rssData = httpGet(rssFeed);
    var allTitles = convertToArray(rssData.getElementsByTagName('title'));
    var allDates = convertToArray(rssData.getElementsByTagName('pubDate'));
    var allText = convertToArray(rssData.getElementsByTagName('text'));
```

I then concatenate the array items together and set an items `innerHTML` to that value (I can provide this code if needed)

the strange thing is that IE8 returns the right number of items, but each item has the value `undefined` as oppsed to the actual value e.g. "Hello world"

I've been battling this for hours and still come up blank ... does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: as requested here is the convert to array function

```
    function convertToArray(htmlCollection) {
        var nodes = [];
        var collectionLength = htmlCollection.length;
        for(i = 0; i < collectionLength; i++) {
            nodes.push(htmlCollection[i]);
        }
        return nodes;
    }
```

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` does the parsing for you? Just use `xmlHttp.responseXML`, not `.responseText`

Comment: "*each item has the value undefined*" - then show us that `convertToArray` function (or wherever you access the items from the NodeList)

Comment: @bergi I've added it above now

Comment: @bergi I also didn't think `responseXML` was supported in IE8?

Comment: I don't know about IE, but you should use it where it is supported (you can still fall back to `new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM')`). Maybe your `htmlCollection`s have `.item(i)` methods? Try to use them if member access doesn't work.

Comment: tried `.item(i)` still not working, I've added a bit of code underneath `var rssData ...` which reads `alert(rssData);` and is returning `[object XMLDocument]` in Firefox, but just `[object]` in IE8, not sure if that is significant?

Comment: Isn't the value of the node contained in a node text below the node? Something along the lines of `htmlCollection[i].firstChild.text`. Or else, how do you access the value you're concatenating? Because some properties might exists on ff/chrome/ie 9, but not in ie8.

Comment: Thank you so much @Py! Hours of misery ended! For some reason `nodes.push(htmlCollection.item(i).firstChild.text)` works in IE8 but not Firefox, for which I'm having to use `nodes.push(htmlCollection.item(i).textContent)` (still not sure why that's happening)

Comment: If you want to make your comment an answer I'll happily accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you'd have to use `.text` and not `.textContent` for ie8, because the `textContent` property doesn't exist in ie.

You can see in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent) that textContent is available only for ie 9+